# Conditional operator and if-else work different?

Tags: java

This is not an error in Java 7

```
return (sum>9)? superDigit(sum,1): sum;
```

whereas

```
if(sum>9) superDigit(sum,1); 
else return sum;
```

this throws a "missing return statement" error. Why?

Answer (score 6):

You're missing return statement in your `if` condition. Actually, it must be:

```
if(sum>9) 
    return superDigit(sum,1); 
else return sum;
```

or you can simplify:

```
if(sum>9) 
    return superDigit(sum,1); 
return sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (sum>9)? superDigit(sum,1): sum;
```

is ternary operator statement.The whole is one statement.

```
if(sum>9) superDigit(sum,1); else return sum;
```

is if/else conditional statement.Each conditional branch must be a complete statement or a stack of statements.